# Constructing a triangle given 2 sides and the inscribed circle's radius

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A Triangle has 2 sides of length 4 and 9. The largest circle than can be drawn in the triangle so as to touch all 3 sides has radius 1 cm. Find the length of the 3rd side.

Comment: You know that inradius is area divided by semiperimeter? What have you done?

Comment: I read the calculations below and understand them. Now my question is: can I construct the triangle by 'straightedge and compass'?    I don not think so....

Comment: @cis your answer is no.  When you have a cubic equation with integer coefficients and the leading coefficient is 1, it can be solved by construction only if it has an integer  root.  The other two roots can be not integers but then their sum would have to be an integer.  Neither is the case with the numbers in the answer below -- so, no go.

Comment: @hardmath You have incorrectly attributed the straightedge and compass question to the OP, when it was asked after the fact by another user.  As a result of your edit, you are implying that the OP was interested in such a construction.

Comment: @heropup:  Having slept on it, I decided the best thing was just to rollback my edit, leaving the bounty (and its erroneous custom msg) intact.  Moderators may edit that custom msg if they choose.

Answer (score 6):

We know that the area of a circle equals its radius times its semiperimeter; i.e., $\| \triangle ABC \| = rs$.  We also know that the area of a triangle is equal to one half of the product of two adjacent sides and the sine of the included angle; i.e., $\|\triangle ABC\| = \frac{1}{2}ab \sin C$.  Without loss of generality, suppose $a = 4, b = 9$.  Then $$13 + c = 36 \sin C.$$  But by the Law of Cosines, $$c^2 = 4^2 + 9^2 - 2(4)(9) \cos C,$$ so eliminating $\angle C$ gives $$c^4-190c^2+104c+4901 = (c + 13)(c^3 - 13c^2 - 21c + 377) = 0.$$  There are actually *two* distinct admissible solutions, corresponding to the positive roots of the cubic $$c^3 - 13c^2 - 21c + 377 = 0,$$ which are approximately $$c \approx 5.9855223908884664799, \quad c \approx 12.183991470265712190.$$
[image]

---

Since this question has been modified and bountied to ask whether the triangle is *constructible*--an entirely different matter that was neither asked by the OP nor mathematically related to the original problem--I will go ahead and furnish an answer.

First, we can see that the cubic for $c$ is [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) over $\mathbb Q$ by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), since if $$p(c) = c^3 - 13c^2 - 21c + 377$$ admits a factorization of the form $g(c)h(c)$ over $\mathbb Q$, one of $g$ or $h$ has degree $1$, but no such rational root exists (simply check $c \in \{\pm 1, \pm 13, \pm 29, \pm 377\}$).  Therefore, $p(c)$ is the minimal polynomial of its roots over $\mathbb Q$, and since $p$ has degree $3$ [which is not an integer power of $2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number#Algebraic_properties), none of the roots is [constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number).

And since there were complaints about "numeric" values for $c$ implying a "loss of generality," the exact value of the two positive roots is readily obtained via [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis#Solution_in_non-real_radicals) for the *casus irreducibilis* as:

$$c = \frac{1}{3} \left( 13 + \frac{29 (2^{2/3}) (-1 + i \sqrt{3})}{\sqrt[3]{-104 + 3i\sqrt{4218}}} - 2^{1/3} (1 + i\sqrt{3})\sqrt[3]{-104 + 3i\sqrt{4218} } \right), \\
c = \frac{1}{3} \left( 13 + \frac{58 (2^{2/3})}{\sqrt[3]{-104 + 3i\sqrt{4218}}} - 2^{4/3} \sqrt[3]{-104 + 3i\sqrt{4218} } \right),$$ or equivalently, using the trigonometric solution,

$$c = \frac{1}{3}\left(13 + 4 \sqrt{58} \sin \left(\tfrac{1}{3} \arcsin \left(\tfrac{52 \sqrt{58}}{29^2}\right) \right) \right), \\
c = \frac{1}{3}\left(13 + 4 \sqrt{58} \cos \left(\tfrac{1}{3} \arccos \left(-\tfrac{52 \sqrt{58}}{29^2}\right) \right) \right).$$

I will **not** entertain demands to show the calculation step by step, as this is clearly not in the spirit of the original question, nor even the question about constructibility, and the method has been established for hundreds of years--the reader who wants to see the calculation should do it for themselves.

Comment: How do you go from the quartic equation to the cubic equation. I actually got a direct cubic equation by using the relation r^2= (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)/s or r^2=1=(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)/(4(a+b+c)) and substituting for a and b (4,9). I gave up since I didn't know how to solve a cubic equation anyway though I know its possible. Can a general quartic be solved? or is itonly because the cubic term is missing?

Comment: @Babji So you mean to ask how to get the exact solutions for the cubic? You know about Cardano's formula?

Comment: The quartic readily admits a factor of the form $c+13$, and the remaining cubic factor is the polynomial given.  The cubic is irreducible and a solution by radicals exists but involves complex numbers.  A trigonometric solution also exists as well.  Read the wikipedia article on the cubic equation.

Comment: Well said, heropup. @Babji You can look here [for details on how to solve the equation], http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=3f4366aeb9c157cf9a30c90693eafc55 . Do you want any method to find the approximate solution like Newton's method, which is I think is more practical in this case.

Comment: When you render $a+b+c=ab\sin C$ and $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C$, trial substitution shows that there is always an extraneous root where $c=-(a+b),C=\pi$ radians.  So that factor can be divided out of the quartic equation, leaving the geometrically correct roots with the cubic factor.

Comment: @cis The WLOG argument specifically pertains to the **choice of the labeling of the side lengths.**  As for a numerical value, unlike you, I did not use any numerical method.  I merely provided the approximate solution rather than the closed-form exact cubic solution because the latter is lengthy, tedious, and not pedagogically relevant.  The point of my answer is to illustrate that two distinct solutions exist, and they can be found by solving a cubic polynomial.  Your use of Newton's method is unnecessary because a closed form solution exists.

Answer (score 4):

There is one and only one circle that touches all 3 sides in a triangle, called the [incircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle). In fact, it is the largest circle that can be drawn within the triangle.

There is a [simple area formula for a triangle](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Triangle_in_Terms_of_Inradius), $A=rs$, where $s$ is the semiperimeter, and $r$ is the inradius [which in this case is $1$], which when combined with the Heron's formula gives:

$$r=1=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}}$$
$$\text{So,  } s = (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$$

Now we have $s=\frac{4+9+c}{2}=6.5+\frac{c}{2}$. Let us dentone $\frac{c}{2}$ by $x$. So substituting: 
$$6.5+x = (6.5+x-4)(6.5+x-9)(6.5+x-c)$$
$$6.5+x = (x+2.5)(x-2.5)(6.5-x)$$
$$6.5+x = -x^3+6.5x^2+6.25x-40.625$$

Thus we have a cubic equation in $x=\frac{c}{2}$. In the next step, we multiply by $8$ to get it in terms of $c$:
$$x^3-6.5 x^2-5.25 x+47.125 = 0$$
$$c^3−13c^2−21c+377= 0$$

Which upon solving, we get three real roots, but only two positive, of which any can be a possible value of $c$, the remaining side:

$$c \approx 5.985522390888466479868150 \text{ or } c \approx 12.18399147026571219021056 $$

Answer (score -1):

[image]

(1) $F=r s = r\dfrac{a+b+c}{2} =\dfrac12 ab \sin(\gamma)
~\Leftrightarrow~
\sin(\gamma) =\dfrac{r(a+b+c)}{ab}$

(2) $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\gamma)
~\Leftrightarrow~
\cos(\gamma) =\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$

(3) $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$

$\Rightarrow~ \dfrac{r^2(a+b+c)^2}{a^2b^2}
+\dfrac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}{4a^2b^2} =1$

$\begin{array}{l l l}
\Leftrightarrow & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2 +(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2  &=4a^2b^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow 
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2+(a^2+b^2)^2 -2(a^2+b^2)c^2 +c^4 
                        &=4a^2b^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow 
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2+a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2
                            -2a^2c^2 -2b^2c^2 +c^4 
                        &=4a^2b^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow 
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2 +(a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2)
                            -2a^2c^2 -2b^2c^2 +c^4 
                        &=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2
                            -2a^2c^2 -2b^2c^2 +c^4 
                        &=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2
                            -c^2( 2a^2 +2b^2)  +c^4 
                        &=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2
                            -c^2\bigl( (a-b)^2 +(a+b)^2 \bigr) +c^4
                        &=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2
                            -c^2(a-b)^2  -c^2(a+b)^2  +c^4
                        &=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2+(a-b)^2 (a+b)^2
                            -c^2(a-b)^2  -c^2(a+b)^2  +c^4
                        &=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2
                    +\bigl( (a-b)^2 -c^2 \bigr) \bigl( (a+b)^2 -c^2 \bigr)
                        &=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow
  & 4r^2(a+b+c)^2
                    +\bigl( (a-b)^2 -c^2 \bigr) 
                        (a+b-c)  (a+b+c) 
                        &=0 
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l l l}
\Leftrightarrow
  & (a+b+c) \bigl\lgroup  4r^2(a+b+c)
                    +\bigl( (a-b)^2 -c^2 \bigr) 
                        (a+b-c)     \bigr\rgroup
                        &=0 \\[1em]
\Leftrightarrow
  & (a+b+c) \bigl\lgroup  4r^2(a+b) +4r^2c 
                    +(a-b)^2(a+b) -(a-b)^2 c 
                        -(a+b)c^2 +c^3     \bigr\rgroup
                        &=0 \\[1em]
\Leftrightarrow
  & (a+b+c) \bigl\lgroup c^3  -(a+b)c^2 
                         +\bigl(  4r^2 -(a-b)^2  \bigr)c
                             +4r^2(a+b) +(a-b)^2(a+b)
                    \bigr\rgroup
                        &=0 \\[1em]
\Leftrightarrow
  & (a+b+c) \bigl\lgroup c^3  -(a+b)c^2 
                         +\bigl(  4r^2 -(a-b)^2  \bigr)c
                    +\bigl( 4r^2 +(a-b)^2 \bigr)(a+b) 
                    \bigr\rgroup
                        &=0 \\[1em]
\end{array}$

To solve:
$c^3 +uc^2 +vc +w=0$, where 
$u=-(a+b)$,   
$v=4r^2 -(a-b)^2$,
$w=\bigl( 4r^2  +(a-b)^2 \bigr)(a+b)$ 
either according to Cardanos formula or in an approximation method.

Annotation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I mistook the Comment on the Question you left a couple of years ago for one by the original poster (who has not been active since then).  If you wanted to pursue the issue of whether the problem is solvable by compass and straightedge (classical constructability), then you could post a new Question (but @OscarLanzi already gave a good answer in his Comment there).

Comment: My goodness: the point was that if someone does a numerical calculation for special sample values, which then delivers sample results in a number corresponding to the example, then he cannot add 'without loss of generality'. Now he has added root expressions in an actionist way, and rated my contribution negatively for reasons of insult; But that is still not 'without loss of generality'. So: just keep playing your kindergarten, I have better things to do.

Comment: The numerical values are sufficient to tell us (for example) that the roots are not integers, so the monic polynomial involved must be irreducible (of degree 3).  I'm not sure who downvoted your Answer, as the one downvote was already there when I came across the Question in the Close Review Queue.  I suspect that I caused @heropup some annoyance with my actions, which I regret, but my motive was to preserve the (very old) Question from being lost to Math.SE.