# Construct a triangle given 2 sides and the radius of the inscribed circle (Euclidean geometry)

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

How do I construct a triangle when I am given 2 sides and the radius of the inscribed circle. Keep in mind the problem must be solved in euclidean geometry so we assume that we don't know trigonometry other fields of "advanced" geometry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing a triangle given 2 sides and the inscribed circle's radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694842/constructing-a-triangle-given-2-sides-and-the-inscribed-circles-radius)

Comment: Such triangles are not unique. Are there any more information on the triangle? If not, start by considering a right-angled triangle.

Comment: Also, take a look at this website: [link](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/23ConstructATriangleGivenTwoSidesAndTheInradius/)